# C# VS2017 IStringable Unreferenced Exception using Windows.Data.Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, uwp

So I'm going to jump straight in.

I'm using `Windows.Data.Json` to convert and use some JSON from a web service. I know about `Newtonsoft.Json.Net`, and some of the others etc. and yes, I am specifically trying to use `Windows.Data.Json`, for company and dependency reasons.

The application has 3 main parts/components.

- A UWP Win 10 app - the main app
- An MVC Web Project - web services for the app
- A Portable Class Library - for shared classes between both

The problem I have is that when I use `JsonObject` in either the MVC web project or the PCL, I am getting the error:

> The type 'IStringable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.

This error is showing up everywhere I use the JsonObject, however, NOT in the UWP app project.

e.g.

```
//Convert string to json object
var apiJsonObj = JsonObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

and

```
cc.Type = apiJsonObj["TYPE"].ToString();
```

I've searched online, and cannot find anything useful about `Windows.Data.Json`, nor the `IStringable`, other than this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.istringable

My project does not have Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract listed in the Add References dialogue, and I cannot find any references to it in the UWP app that I am using, nor any other information that has been of use.

The UWP app and the MVC Web app use literally the same lines of code to interpret the `JsonObject`. The UWP app works. The MVC Web app gives the above error.

I was wondering if anyone else has been using `Windows.Data.Json` successfully, and may have come across this issue, and a fix?

The applications must be as small and independent as possible, hence the small number of references, and not being able to use Json.Net etc.

Comment: I've also seen posts like this: https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D/issues/299 but that don't really contain any real info on a solution other than it will be fixed in VS17. (Dev15) I'm using VS2017 v15.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This error is showing up everywhere I use the JsonObject, however, NOT in the UWP app project.

The `Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract` assembly is [platform specific](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/extension-sdks/windows-universal-sdk). You could not use it in your portable library. It will throw compiling error, though you can add the reference via pick `winmd` file where in the below folder.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\2.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd
```

Currently,`Json.NET` has supported portable library, you could use it to parse json. You could  chose `Json.NET` which does not cause complex assembly dependencies.

Comment: Hey, so this didnt exactly solve my issue, but it answered my question. So I will mark as the answer.